# What is the difference between at the age of and at the ages of?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, difference, plural-forms, singular

What is the difference between at the age of and at the ages of?
singular noun and plural noun?
Please tell me the difference.

Answer (score 1):

“At the age of” is singular and “At the ages of” is plural

You would use the first in referring to just one year, and the second when referring to multiple.

For example:

> At the ages of thirty and thirty one I learnt Spanish.

---

So you might say something like:

> At the ages of 2 and 4, my kids were quite a handful.

And then even if it was more than one kid, but they're the same age, you'd use the singular:

> At the age of 15, my twin boys were just learning to drive.